# PHP prepared statement update form

Tags: php, database, prepared-statement

I will break this question into paragraphs for easier refering;

1. I have a website with a button which plusses a current number from a database with 1.
2. I have now used an "update" form in order to plus the number in the database. I have used prepared statements to do so:

   ```
   <?php
       require_once('connectvars.php');
       $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

           if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
               echo 'Cannot connect.' . mysqli_connect_error(); 
               exit();
               }

           if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE `javascriptbutton` SET `clicks`=? WHERE `id`=?')) { 

               $stmt->bind_param('ii', $clicks, $id);

               $clicks = $_POST['clicks'] + 1; 
               $id = 1;

               $stmt->execute();

               $stmt->close();

           } else {
               echo 'Woops, something went wrong.: ' . $mysqli->error;
           }
   ```

   ?>
3. When the user presses a button in html, it calls a script containing Ajax which refers to the php script above.
4. Everytime the button is pressed, this php file has to get the current "clicks" from the database column "clicks" where id=1 and plus it with 1 and insert it back into the database.
5. I have been researching and looking on my code a lot and I can conclude that it has to do with:

   $clicks = $_POST['clicks'] + 1;

The $_POST['clicks'] should be the current number in the database, and get plussed by 1.

Question:
Do I have to create a select form to get the current clicks out of the database? Or how can I plus the current clicks with 1 and put the new number back into the database till next time a person presses the button?

If there are any of the 5 steps you want to deepen, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use:

```
$mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `javascriptbutton` SET `clicks`=`clicks`+1 WHERE `id`=?")
```

EDIT Full code:

```
    if ($mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `javascriptbutton` SET `clicks`=`clicks`+1 WHERE `id`=?")) { 

        $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
        $id = 1;

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();

    }
```

Comment: like:
$clicks = clicks + 1;
I tried that but it won't work. Is it because I have to write it directly into the mysql string? Since I'm new to prepared statements, I thought that I could just insert it using a "?" just like I did with the "id"

Comment: just use `column = column + 1` MySQL takes care of the rest :)

Comment: I already have $clicks = $clicks + 1; now but it does not seem to make any difference at all. I'm not sure what you mean by column = column but there must be a way to do it without inserting it directly into the mysqli string?

Comment: Yeah, that will fix my problem but I am afraid of processing it directly into the database and that is why I use prepared statements which means that I will define the input later in the script like I have done with "id". Is that not possible to do with "clicks" as well? Or is this my only option? And thank you :)

Comment: prepared statement is only useful for data, when you deal with data like id = '$id' here $id is data, but table columns are not data, are part of the original query